# If the Windows Security icon is disabled, will I get notifications from Windows Security?

Tags: windows-10, security, anti-virus

I know I can disable the icon in the startup tab of Task Manager.

But I'm worried that if I do that, I won't get any notifications from Windows Security. So I was wondering if I would still get the notifications or not.

Comment: Which startup program exactly you intend to disable?

Comment: @harrymc "Windows Security notification icon".

Comment: @John I don't understand your comment. Are you saying I won't get notifications, and that the answer to my question is no?

Comment: If you want the notifications, why are you disabling the icon, instead of just hiding it?

Comment: Because I don't want the **^** "icon" in the systray.

Comment: @John No. The ^ icon only shows when there are hidden icons. When the only one is Windows Security, removing it removes the ^.

Comment: `Just leave the icon. No harm done` - People ask questions about changing the wallpaper. You could also say "Leave the default one. No harm done." I'm asking about what if someone _does_ want to do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SecurityHealthSystray.exe` process can be disabled in the tray.

You will receive security notifications even if it is not running,
although without the icon you may not know about them
([link](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/xts9q6/is_it_okay_to_remove_securityhealthsystrayexe/)).

This process uses very few resources and is not a performance problem.

All these things change radically between Windows versions,
so nothing is certain and nothing lasts forever.
If if today this will work as you like, tomorrow it may not,

You may drag the icon to the tray bar from its "more icons"
part (`^`) to get rid of it.

Comment: `You will receive security notifications even if it is not running, although without the icon you may not know about them` - Then what does it mean receiving it without knowing about it. Either it appears in the bottom right of the screen, or it doesn't. Do you mean that opening Windows Security will show me those notifications?

Comment: I mean that the icon won't be displayed. Windows might or might not tell you that there are new notifications, but you will have to just try and see. You may also not know if Windows Security has encountered a problem. (All these things change radically between Windows versions, so nothing is certain, even my answer as I have not looked at this for some time.)

Comment: OK. So perhaps I wasn't clear enough, but what I meant is will I be notified of a problem, not if there will be a mark on the Windows Security application. But the end of your comment is probably the correct answer - we don't know. Which means I better leave it enabled. Oh well.... Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that that it's tray program that issues the notifications, but rather the main engine of Windows Security, because such a program architecture doesn't make sense. But we need to remember that this is Microsoft, and not all its decisions make sense. I added a small remark to my answer.